# presentViewController does not exist

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I am building a plugin in NativeScript.
When I try to access "presentViewController" method on rootViewController, I get the error "property presentViewContrller does not exist".

> const rvc = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewContrller;
>   rvc.presentViewContrller(myViewController, true, completion() {});

It suggests to use presentViewContrllerAnimatedCompletion which does not accept my view controller.

Could you please assist what part of my code (or maybe setup!) is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right method name is `presentViewControllerAnimatedCompletion` only.

You should combine the parameter names with method name while marshalling Objective C to JS/TS.

`presentViewController:animated:completion`